# Google Maps Android V2 Grey/Blank Screen App

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I am making a new app and I came across an issue. When I launch app(on my physical device and genymotion with google play service enabled both tested) the app launches fine but the screen is all grey, I can only see location button and zoom in and out. I've seen other people having this problem but none of the answers helped. Here is my code. Mby some mistakes were made? Thanks in advance :>

MainActivity.java

```
package tk.chom.randomstudio.alcofinder;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// Constant for defining latitude and longitude
static final LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(40 , -79);

// GoogleMap class
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // verify we can interact with the Google Map
    try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        // Show a satellite map with roads, MapType is used here
        /* MAP_TYPE_NORMAL: Basic map with roads.
        MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE: Satellite view with roads.
        MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN: Terrain view without roads.
        */
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        // Place dot on current location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Turns traffic layer on
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

        // Enables indoor maps
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);

        // Turns on 3D buildings
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);

        // Show Zoom buttons
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        // Create a marker in the map at a given position with a title
        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                position(myPosition).title("Siemano, tu jesteś"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="tk.chom.randomstudio.alcofinder" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="tk.chom.randomstudio.alcofinder.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBEZVa9R8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
</application>
```

Comment: ... no internet connection ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer i think. problem was with weird key behavior. Had to generate it few more times on my pc and then it worked fine, but when I changed project and wanted to use the same key it said it was tempered with or pass was incorrect(it was correct btw) but making a new one fixed the problem. Strange

Answer (score 0):

I think Your `API_KEY` for your map did not set correctly.You need to turn on `google maps v2 android` on `Developer api console`.

Please try to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, you will finally get a map on your phone.

For MainAcitivity`, sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static LatLng goodLatLng = new LatLng(37, -120);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private EditText et_address, et_finalAddress;
    LatLng addressPos, finalAddressPos;
    Marker addressMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        et_finalAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalAddressEditText);


        // Initial Map
        try {

            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // Put a dot on my current location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        // 3D building
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        // Get zoom button
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(goodLatLng)
                .title("Hello"));
    }
```

For more details, please refer to my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bjiang/map_ex/MainActivity.java).

Comment: That's exactly what I follow, still nothing

Comment: You can download the `source code` [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android), and `import` it in your `Android Studio`, it should work.

Comment: Do you run it in the `emulator`? Some `emulator` need to set up  the `Google Service` to run `Google map`